# Filesystem doesn't reliably mount upon EC2 boot

Tags: amazon-ec2, filesystems, ubuntu-16.04, fstab

I've got a mail server (Ubuntu 16.04) running on AWS. Sometimes, when rebooting, the EBS volume that contains all the mail doesn't always mount. This just happened, and I ran `df -H`, noticing the volume was not mounted:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            246M     0  246M   0% /dev
tmpfs            52M  2.0M   50M   4% /run
/dev/xvda1      8.4G  2.6G  5.4G  33% /
tmpfs           256M  4.1k  256M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           256M     0  256M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            52M     0   52M   0% /run/user/1002
```

After mounting it, it's now shown (`/var/vmail`):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            246M     0  246M   0% /dev
tmpfs            52M  2.0M   50M   4% /run
/dev/xvda1      8.4G  2.6G  5.4G  33% /
tmpfs           256M  4.1k  256M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           256M     0  256M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdf       8.4G  5.5G  2.5G  70% /var/vmail
tmpfs            52M     0   52M   0% /run/user/1002
```

This is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
/dev/xvdf   /var/vmail  ext4    defaults,nofail     0 2
```

All I was able to find from `dmesg` is this:

```
[    1.704193] blkfront: xvdf: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[    6.636754] EXT4-fs (xvdf): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

And syslog:

```
Feb 23 20:57:37 mail2 systemd[1]: Found device /dev/xvdf.
Feb 23 20:57:37 mail2 systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/xvdf...
Feb 23 20:57:37 mail2 systemd-fsck[687]: /dev/xvdf: clean, 49282/524288 files, 1401891/2097152 blocks
Feb 23 20:57:37 mail2 systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/xvdf.
Feb 23 20:57:37 mail2 kernel: [    1.367621] blkfront: xvdf: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
Feb 23 20:57:37 mail2 kernel: [    6.412505] EXT4-fs (xvdf): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Feb 23 21:00:36 mail2 kernel: [    1.388299] blkfront: xvdf: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are there an relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: I'm not Linux savvy enough to know which log file to look at. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise in finding things out #

Comment: Edited to include log info

Comment: That just seems to show the device mounting correctly. We would need to see the logs from when it failed to mount.

Comment: That's just it, that was around the time that I booted and it failed to mount. I don't see anything fishy. I'll try to replicate it, but it would involve me rebooting the mail server repeatedly.

Comment: If it is only happening intermittently then I would suggest waiting till you next need to restart and then if it failed to mount again, check the logs before you mount the disk.